# kafka-node asynchronous consumer handler

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

That's how my consumer is initialised:

```
const client = new kafka.Client(config.ZK_HOST)
const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(client, [{ topic: config.KAFKA_TOPIC, offset: 0}],
{
    autoCommit: false
})
```

Now the consumer `consumer.on('message', message => applyMessage(message))`

The thing is `applyMessage` talks to the database using [`knex`](https://knexjs.org/), the code looks something like:

```
async function applyMessage(message: kafka.Message) {
    const usersCount = await db('users').count()
    // just assume we ABSOLUTELY need to calculate a number of users,
    // so we need previous state
    await db('users').insert(inferUserFromMessage(message))
}
```

The code above makes `applyMessage` to execute in parallel for all the messages in kafka, so in the code above given that there are no users in the database yet, `usersCount` will ALWAYS be 0 even for the second message from kafka where it should be 1 already since first call to `applyMessage` inserts a user.

How do I "synchronise" the code in a way that all the `applyMessage` functions run sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to implement some sort of Mutex. Basically a class which queues up things to execute synchronously. Example

```
var Mutex = function() {
  this.queue = [];
  this.locked = false;
};

Mutex.prototype.enqueue = function(task) {
  this.queue.push(task);
  if (!this.locked) {
    this.dequeue();
  }
};

Mutex.prototype.dequeue = function() {
  this.locked = true;
  const task = this.queue.shift();
  if (task) {
    this.execute(task);
  } else {
    this.locked = false;
  }
};

Mutex.prototype.execute = async function(task) {
  try { await task(); } catch (err) { }
  this.dequeue();
}
```

In order for this to work, your `applyMessage` function (whichever handles Kafka messages) needs to return a `Promise` - notice also the async has moved from the parent function to the returned Promise function:

```
function applyMessage(message: kafka.Message) {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve,reject) {
    try {
      const usersCount = await db('users').count()
      // just assume we ABSOLUTELY need to calculate a number of users,
      // so we need previous state
      await db('users').insert(inferUserFromMessage(message))
      resolve();
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Finally, each invocation of `applyMessage` needs to be added to the Mutex queue instead of called directly:

```
var mutex = new Mutex();
consumer.on('message', message => mutex.enqueue(function() { return applyMessage(message); }))
```